# How can a Task's priority be changed?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm a *very* basic user of Azure DevOps. There used to be a UI gadget on the Task page under the Details group that displayed the Task's Priority but as of a short time ago it is no longer available which makes it very difficult to modify a Task's priority. This gadget is still available on a Bug but not a Task. How can I recover/re-enable this gadget so that we can change a Task's priority as needed?

Here's an example of the Details group which used to have a Priority gadget within.
[image]

See the triple dots up at the top right? Click on those.
A menu appears.
Select Customize.
A new View appears which (eventually) allows you to see what's in the Details group.
One of those items is Priority. 
Click on the triple dots to its right and edit it.
Try to enable the display. 
This fails.
A popup says that this is an inherited property that can be hidden or renamed but you cannot enable it from here.

Fine. How does one get to the parent 'process', whatever the heck that is and change the Priority field back to be visible and editable?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps.
Navigate to work items.
View any Task by clicking on the Title field hyper link.
The Task View appears.
On the upper right of the View is a triple dot control. Click it.
A menu appears. Select Customize.
You are now at All processes > Simple Workflow > Task
There are two columns on the right of the page, Details and Deployment.
Under Details is a Priority. It has a strike through to indicate that it is not displayed.
Select Details.
The field highlights and a triple dot appears.
Click the triple dot and select ‘Show on Layout’.

Done.

For me, this didn’t work yesterday. I closed all web pages and Visual Studio. 
Restarted VS and asked it to display the DevOps page.
Looked at Tasks and they had Priority.

Very frustrating and the question is, why did the field go away? It is possible that one of the two other programmers working on this project accidentally did this but this is such a convoluted process to modify it that it would seem unlikely. Did DevOps/Azure change the default template? Maybe. How would I know. In any case, I'm up and working again so thank you everyone for your kind suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing above steps, You can mark it as answer.